# How does AWS Lambda internal pollers manage SQS API calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

in the AWS doc, it is written

> Lambda reads up to five batches and sends them to your function.
> (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling)

I am a bit confused about that part

> "reads up to five batches".

Does it mean:

- 5 SQS ReceiveMessage API calls are made in parallel at the same time ?
- 5 SQS ReceiveMessage API calls are made one by one (each one creating a new lambda environment)

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda, in python for example, uses the `queue.receive_messages` function, to receive messages. This function is able to receive a batch of messages in a single request from an SQS queue.

The default is 10 messages per batch as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-CreateEventSourceMapping-request-BatchSize) and may range to 10000 for standard queues. But there is a limit for simultaneous batches and that's 5 batches, sent to the same lambda.

If there are still messages in the Queue, lambda launches up to 60 more lambdas per minute to consume them.

Finally, event source mapping (lambda's link to the SQS queue) can handle up to 1000 batches of messages simultaneously.

Comment: Ok thank you. for the details. Let's assume there are 5 messages in my standard SQS queue. in that case, does it mean that each polling process could maybe get only 1 message each ?

Comment: It will get a batch, which defaults to 10 messages per fetch. You can limit that to 1 if you'd like with MaxNumberOfMessages parameter.

Comment: Ok, but here in the example I am using, since the 5 polling processes are polling in parallel,
is it possible for the 5 processes to only get 1 message each ?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you specify MaxNumberOfMessages = 1 and you don't structure your code with any while message exist loop. Just Read a message, process it and terminate the lambda event and it will launch more lambdas to process your messages. You can create a simple PoC to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda polls 5 batches in parallel.

Comment: Ok thank you.
Let's assume there are 5 messages in my SQS queue.
in that case, does it mean that each polling process could maybe get only 1 message each ?